# nginx Http2 Push fails when Vary: Accept header set

Tags: nginx, push, http2, webp, content-negotiation

Basically, http2 push using http2_push_preload doesn't work if you set header Vary: Accept on your response because you are doing content negotiation using the Accept request header. I'm using content negotiation to send (http2 push) webp pics instead of jpg to clients that support it.

HTTP/2 Push works for .js, .css files and all in the same call and shows "Push/Other" in Chrome DevTools, but fails for this one unique case (jpg content negotiated to webp), and shows just "Other" (not pushed) in Chrome DevTools.

Content negotiation for brotli, gzip compressions all work fine and get pushed properly using the Vary: Accept-Encoding and same for languages using the Vary: Accept-Language.

Only Vary: Accept fails. 
Please help I'm at the point of giving up.

P.S: I was going through nginx source https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2.c. Do a Crtl+F and you will find cases for only "Accept-Encoding" and "Accept-Language", nothing for "Accept". So I think "Accept" case is not yet supported by nginx??

P.P.S: I'm not overpushing, only using http2 push for the hero image.

Edit: Here's bug ticket on nginx site for those who want to track it:
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1851
https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1817

Edit 2: Nginx team has responded by saying they are not going to support it due to security reasons (you can find the response in the duplicate bug post), which I believe is due to pushing from different origins like CDNs? Anyway, I need this feature, so the only option left is to:

1. Create a custom patch or package.
2. Use some other server software that supports it.
3. Manually implement in website code a feature to rewrite .jpg paths to .jpg.webp if requests are coming from clients that support webp.

(I don't give up :P)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely surprised by this and [Apache does the same](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#push). If you want this to change suggest to raise a bug with nginx but wouldn't be surprised if they didn't prioritise it.

It also seems [the browsers don't handle this situation very well either](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/#items-in-the-push-cache-should-be-matched-using-http-semantics-aside-from-freshness).

HTTP/2 push is fraught with opportunities to over push and this is one example. You should not push if client does not support WebP and you often won't know that with the information that you have at this point. Chrome seems to send webp in the `accept` header when you ask for the HTML for example, but Firefox does not.

Preload is a much better, safer, option that will respect vary headers and also cache status.

Comment: I've gone through the link you mentioned already. I'm not over pushing, just sending the hero image only. I'm doing content negotiation after checking if the request header has webp support. No assumptions made. In nginx it is done by using
    map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
        default "";
        "~*webp" ".webp";
    } 
    and in the server { } area, by doing try_files $uri$webp_suffix

Comment: OK so only push if accept includes webp - like Chrome would when requesting the HTML document. In this case it won't work for Firefix since they don't sent webp in accept header. But as you say at least not over pushing. Answers the same though - raise a bug with nginx and hope they fix it.

Comment: The link you mentioned says http/2 push is tough w.r.t the browser. But I tested it to check the problem is not at the browser end by direct pushing the .webp image variant. The problem I'm facing is at the nginx server side where it is not pushing the file if it has the Accept: Vary.

Comment: Yes like you said Chrome supports it (along with all Chromium based browsers like Brave, Chromium, etc), but I was thinking Chrome user base is very high so it makes a difference. Yes it won't work with firefox.

Comment: Yes but even if that worked, then you may see issues in the browser next. Looks like Chrome fixed their bug by the looks of things so might work, but didn't check the rest of them. Regardless the answer is the same -  raise a bug with nginx and hope they fix it.

Comment: Alright raising bug report. So that's your conclusion too, that it is an nginx bug??

Comment: I imagine they'll argue where it's a bug, or working as intended. As I say Apache does the same, and also intentionally. But yes, you have shown in the code that it's explicit to not send those headers on.

Comment: Personally I think images are a bad candidate to push. I'd really only push critical CSS and critical JS. Google's advice is only to push the minimum needed to fill the idle time: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K0NykTXBbbbTlv60t5MyJvXjqKGsCVNYHyLEXIxYMv0/edit. So I'd say this is potentially a missed opportunity to use Push to it's maximum potential rather than a bug per se.